# A black dome around a space probe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation

The given problem states that

As a result of heating by a nuclear energy source of strength I inside a probe ,its surface temperature is T .The probe is now enclosed within a thin thermal protective shield ,which is black on both sides and attached to the probes surface by a few insulating rods. Find the new surface temperature.

Now according to me this situation is not possible as to obtain thermal equilibrium equal amount of radiation should be emitted and absorbed. In the problem according to me, whatever temperature the space probe will emit radiation which is absorbed by the outer protective shield, but in turn the protective shield should also emit the same radiation inward and therefore, the space probe is just absorbing radiation and not emitting any. Could someone tell me where I went wrong, because the solution states

, When a thin protective shield, which is black on both sides the same radiation process occurs at the outer surface of the shield and so the temperature of the shield must be T, However the shield also emits radiation inwards and consequently the surface of probe absorbs and amount of radiation equivalent to that radiated in the space, this means the new surface temperature must re-radiate a total intensity 2I.[image]

Answer (score 2):

An equal amount of radiation should be emitted and absorbed, but your statement

> in turn the protective shield should also emit the same radiation inward

is incorrect, because the equality of radiation in and out applies to the whole body. Only half the radiation goes inwards.

The easiest way to see the solution is that the radiation into space must be the same as before and equal to the rate of internal nuclear energy generation. This means the temperature of the shield must be similar to $T$ if its surface area is only slightly larger than the ship.

The ship is then back-irradiated by the shield and thus its temperature must rise to re-radiate that energy. It is not possible for the probe to be just absorbing radiation and not emitting any.

If $I$ is the nuclear generation rate, the surface of the probe absorbs $2I$, consisting of $I$ from its interior and $I$ radiated from the inner surface of the shield (which also radiates $I$ into space).

Comment: I understand your solution entirely and it makes a lot of sense, that the total radiation emitted outside should be I only and this should also be the radiation emitted inside by the shield, but when I solve it for isolated bodies like when I write equations for the probe and the shield individually it doesnt work. Could you hint me towards how I can make it match.